# Recover excel file sum

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, list

Hello I explain my problem I try to recover the sum of the absences of each user via an excel file in which a column contains users and other absences however I can not apply a loop to do this. I show you my code

Below the reading of the excel file:

```
print(fichier1)
document1 = xlrd.open_workbook(fichier1)
feuille_1 = document1.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Then I put in list form the 2 columns that interest me:

```
id = []
absence = []
for row in range(1,253):
     id.append(feuille_1.cell(row, 2))
     absence.append(feuille_1.cell(row, 9)
```

From here I am blocked because I can not make a loop that will get me the sum of the absences of each user knowing that in the file there is several lines with the same user but a different number of absence . And so I try to sum up all their absences.

The problem I have encountered is that I can not convert the column of absences to float first.

My excel file [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gonvU.png).

Now i have my dictionary with my value i wish to know how compare two dictionary because i want to compare the number of absence for each user in two dictionary.

Now i have an other excel file and i do the same to it :

```
id1= row[1]
absence2 = []
id3 = []

for row in range(1,360):
       absence.append(float(feuille_1.cell_value(row, 10).replace(",",".")))
       id3.append(id1)

result2 = {}
for name2 in set(id4):
      result2[name2] = 0


for i in range(len(id3)):
       hours2 = float(absence[i])
       name2 = id4[i]
       result2[name2] += hours2

for name2, hours2 in result2.items():
       print(name2 + ":\t" + str(hours2))
```

And i want to compare both dictionary with a code like this :

```
for key in result:
    if result[key]!=result2[key]:
           print("%s not equal"% (key))
```

But i'm wonder if it's worked if in one of dictionary there are more user than the other like that :

```
result={"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
result2={"jazi": 3, "juge": 4, "juha": 1, "lebe": 4, "aba":7, "meze":9}
```

Comment: How does your excel file look?

Comment: I post it below my question

Comment: small tip for the next time: you can edit your question for example to add more information or files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand it right, you have something like this after the for loop:

`id = ["jazi", "juge", "juha", "juha", "lebe", "lebe"]
absence = ["1", "1", "8", "1", "3", "1"]`

and you want to get something like this:

```
{"jazi": 1, "juge": 1, "juha": 9, "lebe": 4}
```

first, initialize the dictionary: (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)
I used the `set()` function to sort out duplicates

```
result = {}
for name in set(id):
    result[name] = 0
```

then, add the hours to the corresponding names:

```
for i in range(len(id)):
    hours = float(absence[i))
    name = id[i]
    result[name] += hours
```

last step, pretty print your result: (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Alternative for pprint:

```
for name, hours in result.items():
    print(name + ":\t" + str(hours))
```

**Same solution using zip() and dict compreshion:**

```
result = {name: 0 for name in set(id)}
for name, hours in zip(id, absence):
    result[name] += float(hours)
```

Comment: Ok but can you show me how you  initialize the dictionary for this example ? I'm novice in Python

Comment: `result = {}` initializes the dictionary https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Comment: Again sorry I probably corrected this error but now a new error appears :                                   AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pprint'

Comment: are you using python 2?

Comment: i added a alternative for pprint.

Comment: I'm using python 3.